# Raphael SVG element overflows below the fold sometimes

Tags: css, raphael

I have a Raphael.js SVG element living inside a div. Occasionally—when the page loads, or when a jquery-ui-draggable is dragged over the main svg node—the whole SVG element (over?)flows almost below the page. That is, if it started at 0,0 and it's 500px high, it jumps to 0,500 all of a sudden, and not always. I've tried setting position:relative but that doesn't seem to fix it. Actually, tweaking the position: in the Chrome debugger makes it "come back", but keeping it there through a page load doesn't fix the issue permanently. It happens maybe half of all page loads.

Anyone know what might be causing this, or at least a way to keep it jammed at the top? I'm rather CSS-ignorant.

Apologies for not having an example; it's part of a large setup that I can't share at the moment. I'm hoping someone has a hunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was some CSS transforms: the input paths weren't in the right coordinate space, so we were doing a `-webkit-transform: translateY(400px) scaleY(-1);` in the `<svg>` element. I'm gonna try scaling the paths before putting them in the DOM instead.

Comment: With no other changes to the DOM, removing the CSS transforms and doing path transformation in Raphael has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you examine the generated source code while it's happening (I use the Web Developer tool and there's an option in there to view the generated source code — and am sure there0s something similar in Chrome) to see if there isn't an element being inserted before it (or that something in your program logic is causing the canvas to be duplicated). I once had some very strange behaviour with Raphael and found that it was linked to my inadvertently loading the same script twice on the page.

I could always suggest absolute positioning too in CSS but that doesn't sound like it would fix the underlying problem.

Good luck and a hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, I'm watching it; the source isn't changing. I think I would notice CSS changes also, so it seems like the rendering engine itself is deciding it belongs in a different spot all of a sudden. Even with position:absolute on the svg element, it still pops down.

Comment: That is strange. Absolute positioning should keep it fixed in place no matter what. Are you sure when you use absolute positioning that there is a parent with non-static position property (e.g. position: relative)? Without seeing it, I'm just guessing here of course. I imagine it would be helpful for you to narrow down the possible causes of the problem. I might give the canvas container a border in CSS and then see when if happens if the canvas itself is expanding or if it really is the containing div that is getting shunted around. Sorry if that's not very helpful.